# How to add +1 to user phone number - via Zapier, Webflow to Sheets, Sheets to Twilio

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, twilio, zapier

I have a form on a Webflow website where a user submits a form including a phone number and I'd like to send an automatic text reply saying "thanks for your submission...".
Twilio requires the number to include the country code for it to send the SMS, however, since this is a local business, I don't really want to require users to enter the country code because they never do and I think it would mess up the UX to throw up error messages until they get it right.
So I was thinking I would,
a) use Zapier to send the user entered phone number (555-555-5555) from Webflow into a Sheet (this works okay)
b) then, use Sheets to take the user number, concatenate with 1 (1-555-555-5555), and then use that number to push back into Twilio to send the SMS;

The problem arises when Sheets receives the new row of data, it deletes any existing formulas that were dragged down.

Then I created a function (see below) to run formula. This function works when I click Run but when I setup a time based Trigger to run every minute it says its completed but doesn't generate the concatenated number.

```
function myFunction() {

  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var cell = activeSheet.getActiveCell();
  var col = cell.getColumn();
  if(cell.getFormula() !== ""){
    var destination = activeSheet.getRange(2,col,activeSheet.getLastRow(), 1);
    cell.copyTo(destination);
  }
}
```

Comment: When you run from a trigger you have to assume that there is no active spreadsheet so openById() and don't use activeCell because most likely tha active cell is going to be A1.  Specify sheets by name and spell out all of the require ranges

Comment: I believe, due to legacy, that numbers without an international format are treated as US numbers. So you might get away with just using the local number here and you can avoid the Google Spreadsheet.

Comment: I do this flow all the time for clients. Set up a sample spreadsheet, share a link here, and I'll show you how to set it up. For your ease in transferring to the real-world/active sheet, name your first sheet of your sample spreadsheet the same as your real-world sheet that receives the form data and include all fields. Fill, say, five rows with realistic-looking dummy data and make sure the phone numbers represent the full variety of formats that might come in from the form. I'll take it from there in illustrating what to do.

Comment: Are you required to use the spreadsheet as an intermediate step? You could just use a [JavaScript](https://zapier.com/help/create/code-webhooks/use-javascript-code-in-zaps) or [Python](https://zapier.com/help/create/code-webhooks/use-python-code-in-zaps) code step in Zapier to do the post-processing of the number and call the Twilio API?

Answer (score 0):

So there was a much easier solution from directly within Zapier.
Essentially, all I needed to do was add the 1 in front on the Phone Number Field I was pulling in from my Webflow form. Zapier automatically concatenates those two numbers.

[Concatenate directly within Zapier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SStR.png)//i.stack.imgur.com/pCB50.png

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of the `openById` function when trying to open the spreadsheet. This will ensure that the spreadsheet needed is indeed opened.

Same goes with the `getActiveSheet` - if these values are in a *specific* sheet, it'd be to replace this with `getSheetByName`.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script SpreadsheetApp Class - openById](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid);
- [Apps Script Spreadsheet Class - getSheetByName](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename).